# Catan Optimal Placement

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, math

Is it possible to calculate the best possible placements for settlements in Catan without using an ML algorithm?

While it is trivial to simply add up the numbers surrounding the settlement (highest point location), I'm looking to build a deeper analysis of the settlement locations. For example, if the highest point location is around a sheep-sheep-sheep, it might be better to go to a lower point location for better resource access. It could also weight for complementary resources, blocking other players from resources, and being closer to ports.

It seems feasible to program arithmetically, yet some friends said this is an ML problem. If it is ML, how would one go about training, as the gameboard changes every game?

Comment: maybe this is the better place to ask: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ever since this question is not related to any programming languages

Comment: shoot thanks I didn't know where to post so I figured I'd give it a go here

Comment: Is not exactly gamedev is more about finding optimal solution for given problem. But the finding optimal starting position or say optimal first move is very difficult, because for that you have to consider all possible follwing moves until end of game also. Thats why friends say it is ML because it will take long time to calculate everything. But with ML you will not calculate everything you will collect sample data or have AI play against AI and hope that ML figures it out. So maybe they can help you at: https://ai.stackexchange.com/  (Hint: go for sheep-sheep-sheep and sheep port or 3:1)

Comment: Can't I assign weights to each of the tiles (ex. sheep = 1.1, brick = 0.9), the closeness to the port, change the weight based on complementary resources, and to try to block other players? Or would it be easier to just deploy ML? In that case, would the training time not be exponentially high due to the randomization of the base board?